# I can’t click add extension in Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can’t click the blue add extension in Firefox.

I am wanting to install an addon in Selenium Firefox.  As far as I can tell the following CSS is changing:

```
.install-wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
```

However, Selenium just does nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add button you have pictured is not part of the page. It's a browser specific dialog and cannot be clicked with Selenium. The quick way to tell this is to right-click on the dialog and see if you see the Inspect option in the context menu. If you don't see it, then it's not part of the page and isn't accessible using Selenium. You might try the keyboard shortcut, ALT+A.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium can only automate Web based applications. Here, you are trying to automate an element in the WebBrower which is a stand alone application installed in your system. If I were using java to write the test script here, I would use selenium to automate the WebApplications and if I encounter any popups on the the Browser, I would try using java classes.